# How to show image in AngularJS ui-grid cell dropdown options?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ui-grid

I have a custom cell template in column definition:
editableCellTemplate: 'templates/image.html'

The template is as follows, but it doesn't show the image.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ApptStatusCtrl">
<select ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" ui-grid-editor>
<option value="2"><img height='20px' 
src='http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/70689.png'></option>
<option value="3"><img height='20px' 
src='http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/70689.png'></option>
<option value="4"><img height='20px' 
src='http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/70689.png'></option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use simple select to display images as it is not supported in any browser. You have to use a custom solution or a plugin. For ref "https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render'

Comment: Any suggestion on what plugin I should use?